# Return value from first column to match condition

Tags: r, data.table

This seems like it should be trivial, but I'm stumped.

Below is a simple illustration of the problem; the real problem is > 1M rows, > 100 columns.  I'm using data.table for performance reasons, but am open to other suggestions.

The "desired" column be should equal to the first non-NA value from columns x, y and z (in sequential order).

```
x <- c(NA,NA,"a")
y <- c(NA,"b","c")
z <- c("d","e","f")
desired <- c("d","b","a")
dt <- data.table(x,y,z,desired)
```

Looking up the column index is fine:

```
dt[,desired.col.ind := apply(dt,1,function(x) which(!is.na(x))[1]),]
```

Returning the column name from the index is fine:

```
dt[,desired.col.name := names(dt)[desired.col.ind],]
```

But all of my attempts to translate the column index or name into its value have failed, below are two of the clearer attempts I've made.

```
dt[,desired.val.1 := get(desired.col.name),] # fail (returns value from column 'z' for all)
dt[,desired.val.2 := apply(desired.col.name,1,function(x) get(x)),] # error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be

```
dt[, desired := na.omit(unlist(.SD))[1], 1:nrow(dt)]
dt
#       x    y z desired
#1: <NA> <NA> d       d
#2: <NA>    b e       b
#3:    a    c f       a
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(x,y,z)
```

Comment: How would that be generalized to look for non-NAs in only a subset of columns?

Comment: @peachy, Just specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` i.e. `dt[, desired := na.omit(unlist(.SD))[1], 1:nrow(dt), .SDcols = x:y]`

Answer (score 3):

A non-data.table option. Not sure if this would be slower or not.

```
ind <- cbind(1:nrow(dt), max.col(!is.na(dt[, c('x', 'y', 'z')]), 'first'))
setDF(dt) #necessary to support array indexing
dt$desired <- dt[ind]   
dt
#      x    y z desired
# 1 <NA> <NA> d       d
# 2 <NA>    b e       b
# 3    a    c f       a
```

Benchmark

```
dt <- data.table(x,y,z)

dt <- rbindlist(replicate(1e4, dt, simplify = F))
df <- as.data.frame(dt)

microbenchmark(
  dt = {dt[, desired := na.omit(unlist(.SD))[1], 1:nrow(dt)]},
  df1 = {ind <- cbind(1:nrow(df), apply(!is.na(df[, c('x', 'y', 'z')]), 1, which.max))
          df$desired <- df[ind] },
  df2 = {ind <- cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df[, c('x', 'y', 'z')]), 'first'))
          df$desired <- df[ind] }, # akrun's imporvement to df1
  times = 10
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#    dt 345.570477 384.211345 403.661789 408.844811 418.096925 452.655327    10
#   df1 108.865365 116.901067 133.166031 120.619020 130.211443 186.128229    10
#   df2   1.915489   1.953233   2.987614   2.082464   2.470157   8.281857    10
```

Comment: I think `max.col` would be more faster i.e. `cbind(seq_len(nrow(dt)), max.col(!is.na(dt), 'first'))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that is faster. I wasn't aware of that function.